# SQL Error 'ORA-00904' When Retrieving Data From an XML File Via XMLQuery

Tags: sql, xml, select, oracle-sqldeveloper, qxmlquery

I've been trying for days now to retrieve data from an XML file with a SELECT statement in SQL Developer but I constantly get the 'ORA-00904' when trying to execute the statement. So far, these are the steps I've been following:

1. Create the table and directory where I want the XML data to be stored in:
   `CREATE TABLE PLAYER OF XMLTYPE; / CREATE DIRECTORY PLDIR AS 'C:\Users\marta\OneDrive\Escritorio\UOC\Sem3\ABD\PR2'; /`
2. Insert into my PLAYER table said data:
   INSERT INTO PLAYER VALUES (XMLTYPE(bfilename('PLDIR', 'InfoPlayersWPT.xml'),nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')))
   /
   So far so good. The issue appears when I try to execute the SELECT statement [image]

What could it be? I've changed the $Name parameter a million times as well as the Name field but nothing changes. The thing is that in the XML file, these are the fields:
[image]

--Update--
I've modified a little bit the structure and this is the new error I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSSZ4.png)
I've reached a point where I don't get if there could be a problem with my database connection or if the variable are incorrect.

Any form of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ORA errors are often due to the drivers.  Not all Oracle driver use the same Comment Text (query) and work with all version of Oracle.  It is best to use an Oracle Driver.  I would check the connection string to see what driver is being used.  Oracle Drivers are ODBC drivers.  Your error is due to the column name in the database not matching the column name in your query.  This may be due to connecting to the wrong server or connecting to the wrong database on the server.

Comment: I've checked the tnsnames.ora file and I can't find any evidence of issues regarding the database connection. I'm really stuck right now.

Comment: Please post your data and query attempts as formatted text, not as images, so we can copy them to run them ourselves.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/266304

Answer (score 1):

Your table doesn't have a `name` or `id` column. Your query is trying to get those, while also transforming the XML to an `info` node making the `id` a node rather than an attribute, but you still don't extract the values from that new XML. You don't need to though.

If the document only has one player (which seems unlikely with the outer node 'Players') then you can get the data with an XMLQuery call for each value:

```
select XMLQuery('/Players/Player/@id' passing p.object_value returning content) as id,
  XMLQuery('/Players/Player/Name/text()' passing p.object_value returning content) as name
from player p
```

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Francinsco Navarro Compán |

But it's a bit simpler, particularly if you add more data items, to use a single XMLTable instead:

```
select x.id, x.name
from player p
cross apply XMLTable(
  '/Players/Player'
  passing p.object_value
  columns id number path '@id',
    name varchar2(30) path 'Name'
) x
```

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Francinsco Navarro Compán |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Db-Z7j00)

... which would also handle multiple players in each XML document.